# Qual a finalidade das pastas "ASP.Net"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

No **Visual Studio** ele me oferece a opção de "Adicionar Pasta ASP.NET".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quais seriam as finalidades delas?
Se possível gostaria que falasse ao menos um pouco sobre cada uma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme a documentação [**Layout de Site Web do ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ex526337(v=vs.100).aspx)

### App_Browsers

Contém as definições do navegador (arquivos `.Browser`) que o ASP.NET usa para identificar navegadores individuais e determinar as suas capacidades. Para mais informações, veja [**Browser Definição Arquivo Schema (browsers Element)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms228122(v=vs.100).aspx) e [**Como: Detectar tipos de navegadores e recursos do navegador em páginas da Web do ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/3yekbd5b(v=vs.100).aspx).

### App_Code

Contém código-fonte para classes utilitárias e de negócios objetos (por exemplo, arquivos `.cs`, `.vb` e `.jsl`) que você deseja compilar como parte do seu aplicativo.Em um aplicativo compilado dinamicamente, o ASP.NET compila o código na pasta `App_Code` na solicitação inicial para o seu aplicativo. Itens desta pasta são recompilados quando as alterações são detectadas.

> **Nota:** Tipos de arquivos arbitrários podem ser colocados na pasta `App_Code` para criar objetos de tipo forte. Por exemplo, colocando arquivos de serviço Web (arquivos `.wsdl` e `.xsd`) na pasta `App_Code` cria tipos proxies rígidos.

Código na pasta `App_Code` é referenciado automaticamente em sua aplicação. Além disso, a pasta `App_Code` pode conter subpastas de arquivos que precisam ser compilados em tempo de execução. Para obter mais informações, consulte [**Pastas de código compartilhado em sites da Web ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx) e [**codeSubDirectories elemento for compilation (ASP.NET Settings Esquema)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/54dwfbb7(v=vs.100).aspx).

### App_Data

Contém arquivos de dados do aplicativo incluindo arquivos MDF, arquivos XML, bem como outros arquivos de armazenamento de dados. A pasta `App_Data` é usada pelo ASP.NET 2.0 para armazenar um aplicativo do banco de dados local, que pode ser usado para manter informações sobre participação e função.Para obter mais informações, consulte [**Introdução à Associação**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx) e [**Noções básicas sobre gerenciamento de papéis**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.100).aspx).

### App_GlobalResources

Contém recursos (arquivos `.resx` e `.resources`) que são compilados em assemblies com alcance global. Recursos na pasta `App_GlobalResources` são fortemente tipados e pode ser acessados programaticamente. Para obter mais informações, consulte Visão geral sobre recursos de página da Web ASP.NET.

### App_LocalResources

Contém recursos (arquivos `.resx` e `.resources`) que estão associados com uma determinado página, controle de usuário, ou página mestra em um aplicativo. Para obter mais informações, consulte [**Visão geral sobre recursos de página da Web ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ykzx33wh(v=vs.100).aspx).

### App_Themes

Contém uma coleção de arquivos (arquivos `.skin` e `.css`, bem como arquivos de imagem e recursos genéricos) que definem a aparência de páginas e controles Web ASP.NET. Para mais informações, acessar o link [**Visão Geral de Temas e Aparências ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ykzx33wh(v=vs.100).aspx).

> **Nota:** O conteúdo das pastas da aplicação, com exceção da pasta `App_Themes`, não é usado em resposta às solicitações da Web, mas pode ser acessado à partir do código da aplicação.

### App_WebReferences

Contém arquivos de referência de contrato (arquivos `.WSDL`), esquemas (arquivos `.xsd`) e arquivos de descoberta de documento (arquivos `.disco` e `.discomap`) definindo uma referência da Web para uso em um aplicativo. Para obter mais informações sobre como gerar o código para serviços Web XML, consulte [**Tool WSDL (Web Serviços Description Idioma) (WSDL.exe)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx).

### Bin

Contém assemblies compilados (arquivos `.dll`) para controles, componentes, ou outro código que você deseja fazer referência na sua aplicação. As classes representadas por código na pasta Bin são automaticamente referenciados em sua aplicação. Para obter mais informações, consulte [**Pastas de código compartilhado em sites da Web ASP.NET**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx).